# mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource (on simple query)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm about ready to pull my hair out, I can not figure out why this is giving me an error, I do all my other SQL queries like this without a single problem. What am I missing here?

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db("tpeoria_main", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM message WHERE to=1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr><td>".$row['from']."</td><td>".$row['body']."</td></tr>";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

[image: Structure]

[image: Database]

Comment: mysql_query("SELECT * FROM message WHERE to=1")or die(mysql_error()) to see the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`to` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

You need to encase it in tick marks.

```
WHERE `to` = ...
```

You also need to stop using `mysql_` functions. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Thought of that being a possibility right after posting this, changed 'to' and 'from' to sender and receiver and everything works now. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like I'll spend the few days switching to MySQLi

Comment: @TylerSiegrist You're doing yourself a great favor.

Answer (score 1):

The previous is correct.  ADO is definitely preferred, but in answer to your question, you need to use "_fetch_row()" rather than "_fetch_array()."  When you call "_fetch_array()" there is only one result and nothing to iterate through in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is here "$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM message WHERE **to=1**");"..
you can not use a reserved word just like this..use quotes for this type of reserved words..
like 'to'.
refer the link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html for other reserved words in mysql